# How to transform a callback hell into promise?

Tags: javascript, express, callback, promise, bluebird

Taking into account this example:

```
app.get('/url/:param', function(req, res, next) {
  var param = req.params.param;
  method1(param, function(err, model) {
    if(err) return next(err);
    method2(model, function(err, models) {
      if(err) return next(err);
      if(models.length > 0) {
        method3(mode, models, function(err, models2) {
          res.render("index.html", {model: model, models: models, models2: models2});
        });
      } else {
        res.render("index.html", {model: model, models: models});
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Is there a way to simplify this example using promises?
Look that all methods are dependants and have validations like `if(models.length > 0)`
Furthermore I need to group the `res.render` in a unique place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming Bluebird, utilizing the library features and removing the nesting:

```
var api = Promise.promisifyAll({method1:method1,method2:method2:method3:method3});
api.method1Async(req.params.param).then(function(res){
     return [method2Async(res),{model:res}];
}).spread(function(res,result){
     result.models = res;
     if(models.length > 0){
         return method3Async(mode,res).then(function(res){
             result.models2 = res;
         }).return(result);
     }
     return results;
}).then(function(results){
     res.render("index.html",results);
}).catch(next); // also handle render errors
```

Alternatively, you can do something like which has even less nesting:

```
var api = Promise.promisifyAll({method1:method1,method2:method2:method3:method3});
var p1 = api.method1Async(req.params.param);
var p2 = p1.then(api.method2Async);
var p3 = p2.then(function(models){ 
    if(models.length > 0) return api.method3Async(mode,models);
});
Promise.all([p1,p2,p3]).spread(function(r1,r2,r3){
    var results = {model:r1,models:r2};
    if(models.length > 0) results.models2 = r3;
    res.render("index.html",results);
}).catch(next)
```

Or, you can use Bluebird coroutines (needs --harmony-generators flag)

```
var api = Promise.promisifyAll({method1:method1,method2:method2:method3:method3});
Promise.coroutine(function*(){
    var model = yield method1Async(req.params.param);
    var models = yield method2Async(model);
    if(models.length > 0){
        var models2 = yield method3Async(mode,models);     
    }
    res.render("index.html",{model:model,models:models,models2:models2});
})().catch(next); // should probably extract to a clear method rather than self invoke
```

Comment: +1 for the 2nd example - although I'd add that in some cases it may be possible to directly use `res.render("index.html", {model:r1,models:r2,models2:r3});` (if there are no "key exists in object" checks in the view)

Comment: I even took that shortcut in the coroutines version, but technically - good point.

Comment: Wow, the third example is really cool since it's like synchronous programming, but i'm a javascript beginner and perhaps not as simple as it seems. The second example seems to be a good way but you need to repeat the validations.

Comment: You can mix the lack of checking from the third option to the second one and save the double check. I didn't want to assume you can pass undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. You can reduce this to one promise that fails or succeeds, and install `next` and `res.render` as the respective handlers. However, since the results are dependent on all the previous ones, the pyramid stays the easiest. Assuming [Q.js](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference):

```
app.get('/url/:param', function(req, res, next) {
  Q.nfcall(method1, req.params.param).then(function(model) {
    return Q.nfcall(method2, model).then(function(models) {
      if(models.length > 0)
        return Q.nfcall(method3, mode, models).catch(function(err) {
          // you're not dealing with errors here
          // omit this `.catch()` call if you want to let it reach the `next()`
        }).then(function(models2) {
          return {model: model, models: models, models2: models2};
        });
      else
        return {model: model, models: models};
      }
    });
  }).done(function(results) {
    res.render("index.html", results);
  }, next);
}
```

Comment: Though I'm generally a fan of promises, it isn't immediately clear that this is simpler than what the OP started with.  I'm sure there are some advantages to it, but simplicity isn't really one of them.  I'm also wondering about the error checks that the OP had in their version.

Comment: @jfriend00 he is calling `next` in the `.done` handler at the end. It has the same error handling OP had, just less verbose.

Comment: the OP forgot one `if (err)` check, which is enough to cause extremely hard to find bugs (equivalent to `on error resume next`). So it's not the same.

Comment: @Esailija: You're right, I've adapted the solution.

Answer (score -2):

If I got you right and If you need to make a lot of nested statements, maybe you could check [this](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async) out. Async can help you out calling various functions on the row (there are a lot of ways to accomplish it using Async, see its documentation further) and you can aling all statements together.

Comment: Async is like a slower, less capable and clunkier version of Bluebird promises, without all the benefits like good syntax and throw safety we get from Bluebird and promises.